# Keeping SQLAlchemy session alive when streaming a Flask Response

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to stream large CSVs to clients from my Flask server, which uses Flask-SQLAlchemy.

When configuring the app (using the factory pattern), `db.session.close()` is called after each request:

```
@app.after_request
def close_connection(r):
    db.session.close()
    return r
```

This configuration has worked great up until now, as all the requests are short lived. But when streaming a response, the SQLAlchemy session is closed prematurely, throwing the following error when the generator is called:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <Question> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'offered_answers' cannot proceed
```

Pseudo-code:

```
@app.route('/export')
def export_data():
    answers = Answer.query.all()
    questions = Question.query.all()
    def generate():
        Iterate through answers questions and write out various relationships to csv

    response = Response(stream_with_context(generate()), mimetype='text/csv')
    return response
```

I've tried multiple configurations of using / not using `stream_with_context` and global flags in `def close_connection` to not automatically close the connection but the same error persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@app.after_request` was closing the database session before the generator to stream the file was ever invoked.

The solution was to migrate `db.session.close()` to `@app.teardown_request`. `stream_with_context` must also be used when instantiating `Response`.

Comment: Flask-sqlalchemy already does the session cleanup stuff, so you should not need to implement your own:

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L805

Comment: @codeape Flask-sqlalchemy does indeed call `session.remove()`. However, my tests are failing when I completely remove the `@app.teardown_request` function. More to come when I can dive a bit deeper.